# Keycloak Example - The method getValue() is undefined for the type UserCredentialModel

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to handle keycloak's Custom User Storage SPI with the example provided.
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/user-storage-simple

When launching `mvn clean install wildfly:deploy` while Keycloak is launched, I get 3 errors from this file `PropertyFileUserStorageProvider.java`:

> variable cred of type org.keycloak.models.UserCredentialModel cannot find symbol (method getValue())

I don't get why I am facing those errors.
They also use this `getValue` method in the documentation.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi

Java & Maven versions

- Java Version 1.8.0_20
- Apache Maven 3.6.2

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserCredentialModel class has changed a lot in the latest Keycloak release 8.0.0

It looks like the "quick start examples" need some fixes to work with this release

Something like :

```
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, CredentialInput input) {
        // No need to check input is of type UserCredentialModel since there no need to cast it anymore
        if (!supportsCredentialType(input.getType())) return false;

        String password = properties.getProperty(user.getUsername());
        if (password == null) return false;
        // Input Password can now be obtained using the getChallengeResponse() method of the CredentialInput  type
        return password.equals(input.getChallengeResponse());
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your help ! This example works fine with your code. Can you provide any link which talks about this getChallengeResponse ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have more to say about this getChallengeresponse() method. I discovered it when switching to Keycloak 8.0.0 . In [UserCredentialModel](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/4553234f649f9b7db7acbed573c0cbb68488f0cf/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/UserCredentialModel.java) , you can see that it is populated with an input password.

Comment: I do not have the password coming from a property file. I will be getting the username and password from Keycloak login page. Any idea how i can use the above solution by grabbing the password from KC Login page?